# Computed values in a object | Svelte

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet, svelte, svelte-component

I am coding some projects to learn Svelte and I have been trying to make something similar to a spreadsheet where a user type or change numbers and that reactively make some calculus with a predefined formula (the user can not change the formula). I have tried but I can not do it reactively.

For this I have created a component call Spreadsheet that has two props, the data and the columns, similar to how Quasar do it for [Tables](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#Example--Basic).

[Here](https://svelte.dev/repl/a87904776ebf4fe0813e6b190690ca77?version=3.16.0) is the REPL with the example.

The idea is that a user change the values on the `females, males and area` columns and that change the value of the `density` column reactively with `poblationDensity` formula.

```
/* App.svelte */
<script>
  import Spreadsheet from "./Spreadsheet.svelte";

    const poblationDensity = (females, males, area) => {
    return (females + males) / area;
  };

  let data = [
        {
      "id": 1,
      "animal": "White-mantled colobus",
      "females": 13,
      "males": 33,
      "area": 109
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "animal": "Woodpecker, red-headed",
      "females": 99,
      "males": 88,
      "area": 252
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "animal": "White-necked raven",
      "females": 34,
      "males": 36,
      "area": 362
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "animal": "Baleen whale",
      "females": 24,
      "males": 67,
      "area": 457
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "animal": "Tiger",
      "females": 89,
      "males": 20,
      "area": 476
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "animal": "White spoonbill",
      "females": 56,
      "males": 85,
      "area": 358
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "animal": "Giant anteater",
      "females": 83,
      "males": 98,
      "area": 236
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "animal": "White-fronted capuchin",
      "females": 72,
      "males": 44,
      "area": 163
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "animal": "Raccoon, crab-eating",
      "females": 78,
      "males": 61,
      "area": 410
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "animal": "Turtle, long-necked",
      "females": 5,
      "males": 77,
      "area": 472
    }
    ];

  const cols = [
    {
      name: "id",
      label: "#"
    },
    {
      name: "animal",
      label: "Animal"
    },
    {
      name: "females",
      label: "Females"
    },
    {
      name: "males",
      label: "Males"
    },
    {
      name: "area",
      label: "Area"
    },
    {
      name: "density",
      label: "Density",
      computed: {
        args: ["females", "males", "area"],
        method: poblationDensity
      }
    }
  ];
</script>

<main>
    <Spreadsheet {data} {cols} />
</main>
```

```
/* Spreadsheet.svelte */
<script>
    export let data = [];
  export let cols = [];
</script>

<style>
    .numeric {
        width: 70px;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        {#each cols as col}
        <th>{col.label}</th>
        {/each}
    </tr>
    {#each data as item}
    <tr>
        {#each cols as col}
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="{col.name !== 'animal' && 'numeric' }"
                             value={col.computed ? 0 : item[col.name]} 
                />
                </td>
        {/each}
    </tr>
    {/each}
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There it is an example. https://svelte.dev/repl/a87904776ebf4fe0813e6b190690ca77?version=3.16.0

Comment: Please post this code example into your question for future reference. Other users who looks for the same problem might won't find your link later anymore.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for your advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice example!

So first thing is to actually connect your computing function, that is `poblationDensity`, to what's displayed. We can change the value of your `<input >` field like so:

```html
value={col.computed ? col.computed.method(item) : item[col.name]}
```

I've adapted your function a little to make this work:

```js
const poblationDensity = ({ females, males, area }) => {
  return (females + males) / area;
};
```

With this, we've got the correct display. Now we need to get the values.

In Svelte, the most common way to get the value of an `<input />` is [two-way binding](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element_property). And it also works with object properties!

In our case, what we need is to bind to the value of the field, so `bind:value={...}`. Let's add this to our example. For this, we need to separate the markup for read-only (computed) values:

```html
{#if col.computed}
  <input
    type="text"
    class={col.name !== 'animal' && 'numeric'}
    value={col.computed.method(item)} />
{:else}
  <input
    type="text"
    class={col.name !== 'animal' && 'numeric'}
    bind:value={item[col.name]} />
{/if}
```

And... Well, here we are! Missing complete! [Updated REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c2ccedd9580f4f0d9b63e559dae75870?version=3.16.1)

Each time a value is updated, `bind:value` will update it in the `data` array. Svelte knows about this change and rerenders the affected rows accordingly. At this point, the computed values are recomputed.

Another approach would be to have an intermediate array to hold the computed values. For this, Svelte offers [reactive declarations & statements](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations). Their alien look make them a little bit intimidating at first, but once you get used to them, they feel like magic!